# Uniform Spaces: Completeness

Tags: category-theory, metric-spaces

**Attention**

This thread has been generalized to uniform spaces as general metric spaces.

**Context**

The context was the equivalence:
$$K\text{ compact}\iff K\text{ totally bounded, complete}$$
That is a purely topological notion compared to a purely uniform notion and a hybrid notion.

**Problem**

Given a uniform structure $\mathcal{U}$.

Is there a way to define completeness intrinsically:
$$\mathcal{U}\text{ complete}:\iff\ldots$$
The usual way is extrinsically via filters:
$$\mathcal{U}\text{ complete}:\iff\left(\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{F}\text{ cauchy}\implies\mathcal{F}\text{ converges}\right)$$
*(Note that filters are an order-theoretic notion!)*

Comment: completeness does depend on the metric, does it not? I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Does totally bounded have a categorical definition?

Comment: Yes completeness depends on the metric since cauchyness. Moreover one might ask (and I guess that was your question) wether two inequivalent metrics give rise to the same complete uniform space. Actually I'm not quite sure either but what I can say is that of course its not a categorical notion as the categorical product but it is a notion due to a specific category namely the category of metric spaces...

Comment: Which category is this -- in particular, which set of maps does it include? I can imagine several categories whose objects are all metric spaces.

Comment: Yes I thought about it too. I mean either it includes only distance preserving maps as morphisms or it does also include contraction or even more general Lipschitz continuous maps. I would say lets start for convenience with the distance preserving maps though I guess for issues like completeness or compactness the better choice would be lipschitz maps as morphisms...

Comment: You ask for a description of completeness then say you'd like one of compactness. Is this a mistake? Also, would you agree with replacing "the" with "*a*" as I've done in my latest edit here? :)

Comment: Yes thats fine but let's keep with the set up syntax ;) (">" is used to give blockquotes) Well if you find something suitable for completeness then compactness will be just that plus total boundedness, isn't it?

Comment: (It's also commonly used to highlight questions, but suit yourself.) But now the same question arises of whether "totally bounded" has a categorical definition. It's just a bit unclear (to me). Never mind :)

Comment: What do you mean by categorical definition?