# Definition of Equivalent Norms

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, intuition

Two norms $F,G$ are equivalent when there are constants $a,b$ such that $aF \le G \le bF$.  I'm reading about this idea, and so far I've seen that equivalence of norms implies that the underlying space $X$ has the same topology with respect to either norm.  Maybe it preserves even more properties than this too.

But I'm finding it very difficult to use this property when doing proofs or problems because although it's very simple to state, I don't immediately see what it is saying.  In comparison, when you define 'equivalence' in other settings, like in the definition of an isomorphism of abelian groups or a continuous map, it's very clear that a certain operation or object is being preserved as you pass across a map.

To be concrete, here are my questions:

(1) Is there another way to characterize when norms are equivalent that might provide more intuition for what it says about is being preserved

and (2) is there a way to show that this definition is the one you want by starting with something more fundamental (like saying that the norms induce the same topology) and then proving that it's equivalent to the stated definition?

Any intuition for the definition would be helpful for either of these questions.

Comment: It says that a convergent sequence say $\{x_n\}$ in the one norm is also convergent in the other norm, but I think you know that.

If $\|x_n-x\|_F\rightarrow 0$, then $\|x_n-x\|_G\leq b\|x_n-x\|_F\rightarrow 0$. Maybe you can try to verify that if for each sequence that is convergent in the $F$-norm it follows that it is also convergent in the $G$-norm implies that there is a constant $b$, such that $\|.\|_G\leq b\|.\|_F$ i.e $F$ is stronger than $G$.

Comment: Equivalent norms define the same algebraic uniform space, i.e. a space that has a notion of cauchyness and that respects the algebraic structure.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, my 4 October 2006 sci.math post [Lipschitz, uniformly, and topologically equivalent metrics](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5213111) might be of use.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro So equivalent norms correspond to Lipschitz equivalent metrics on the vector space?  Is the idea to take away from this that equivalent norms preserve more than just convergence of sequences, they also preserve cauchyness of sequences?

Comment: I highly encourage you to read my answer. I know it got very veeery long but it might truly pay off if you can make it to the end!! *(I spend more than 5 hours to compose it.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S I will and thanks for doing it I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3281410: I just added a full proof. Have fun! ;)

Comment: What you said sounds correct, but keep in mind that not every metric defined on a vector space can be a metric induced by some norm defined on that vector space. For instance, every metric induced by a norm is compatible with the algebraic structure in a way that an arbitrary metric on the vector space might not be. But it's certainly true that the metrics induced from your "equivalent norms" wind up being what I called "Lipschitz equivalent metrics". Incidentally, the terminology I used is not (entirely) standard, but it does avoid the ambiguity one often encounters in this topic.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: *Adding:* That's all nice result on Lipschitz-continuity but the question is rather what one wants at the end than what would be a technical implementation. Equivalent metrics, as you certainly know, define precisely the same uniform structure while weakly equivalent metrics only the same topology.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: More precisely: $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}'\iff\forall z\in\Omega\forall\varepsilon>0\exists \Delta_{x\varepsilon},\delta_{x\varepsilon}>0:B'_\delta(z)\subseteq B_\varepsilon(z)\subseteq B'_\Delta(z)$ $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{U}'\iff\forall\varepsilon>0\exists R_\varepsilon,r_\varepsilon>0:B'_{r\varepsilon}\subseteq B_\varepsilon\subseteq B'_{R\varepsilon}$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: *Analogy*: What you want is a measure so what you need is a a sigma algebra rather than what you want is a sigma algebra and what you get is a measure.

Comment: @user3281410: Did you know that there are actually circumstances where one truly considers the category of normed spaces, i.e. where the homomorphisms are necessarily isometric? An example I have in mind are C*-algebras like the space of bounded operators over a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Freeze_S I haven't really run across that yet.  It might take me quite a while to go through your post, but I'll refer back to it as I keep learning about topology.  In the meantime, I hope you aren't offended if I accept one of the other answers.  From what I can tell you're saying that equivalence of norms is exactly the property that preserves uniform structure, while weak equivalence preserves just topological structure.  Since I haven't heard of uniform structure before this thread, I'll have to slowly look into it.

Comment: @user3281410: Everything alright. ;) But keep digging for truth. *(No shallow results!!!)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful to consider an example of two norms $F$ and $G$ of a vector space $X$ not being equivalent to each other. What it means is that at least one of the quantities $\sup\limits_{x \in X}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$ or $\sup\limits_{x \in X}\frac{G(x)}{F(x)}$ is unbounded, i.e. there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of vectors in the space such that $\frac{F(x_n)}{G(x_n)}$ or $\frac{G(x_n)}{F(x_n)}$ diverges to $+\infty$ when $n \to \infty$.

Intuitively, if a norm $G$ is equivalent to a norm $F$, $G$ neither stretches too much, nor shortens too much the lengths of the vectors already assigned by $F$. The "new" $G-$length of every vector is within a bound of its "old" $F-$length: $\forall x \in X, \quad  aF(x) \leq G(x) \leq bF(x)$. There are not parts of the space stretched or shrunk arbitrarily much.

For an example of two nonequivalent norms, consider the space $C^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ of real twice continuously differentiable functions defined on $[0,1]$. Define the two norms $F(x(t)) = \sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]}|x(t)|$ and $G(x(t)) = |x(0)| +  \sup\limits_{t \in [0,1]}|x'(t)|$. Now, if we look at the sequence $x_n(t) = \sin(n\pi t)$, then the $F-$norm of every $x_n$ is $1$ while $G(x_n) = n\pi$. The unit $F-$sphere is torn away to infinity when the $G$ norm is used.

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Does one of two in-equivalent norms always diverge on the unit ball of the other?

Comment: Yes. Once you find a sequence of vectors $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ such that $F(x_n)/G(x_n) \to \infty$, say, you can always consider the sequence $(x_n/F(x_n))_{n \geq 0}$ which lies on the unit $F-$sphere and still has the property that $F(x_n/F(x_n))/G(x_n/F(x_n)) = F(x_n)/G(x_n) \to \infty$.

Comment: That's very helpful.  I'm trying to picture this as well as I can. If you don't mind, do you know if it's also true that one norm has to diverge on any ball of the other, not necessarily at the origin?

Answer (score 6):

## PROBLEM

**Answer**

> Equivalent norms define the same uniform vector space.

**Explanation**

> Completeness is a concept by uniform vector spaces.

**Demonstration**

Given the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the metrics:
$$d(x,y):=|y-x|$$
$$d'(x,y):=\arctan|y-x|$$

Then one obtains:
$$\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{N}'\quad\mathcal{U}\neq\mathcal{U}$$

Concluding problem.

---

## PROOF

**Identification**

Given normed spaces $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$.

Regard the category:
$$\mathrm{UVS}:\quad\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Identification:
$$\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':x\mapsto x$$

Linearity follows:
$$\Phi(x+y)=x+y=x+'y=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot x=\lambda\cdot'x=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)$$

But by the below:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_L(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{B}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Explicitely that is:
$$\|x\|'=\|\Phi x\|'\leq\|\Phi\|\cdot\|x\|$$
$$\|x'\|=\|\Phi^{-1}x'\|\leq\|\Phi^{-1}\|\cdot\|x'\|'$$

Concluding proof.

---

## CATEGORIES

**Topological Vector Spaces**

Note for linear maps:
$$\Phi\in\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\implies\Phi^{-1}\in\mathcal{L}(\Omega',\Omega')$$

Continuous at zero:
$$\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega:\Phi^{-1}(\mathcal{N}_{\Phi0})\subseteq\mathcal{N}_0\}$$

It holds equality:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Homomorphisms:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad\Phi(\mathcal{N})=\mathcal{N}'$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

Basic entourages:
$$B_N:=\{(x,y):(y-x)\in N\}\subseteq\Omega\times\Omega$$

Uniform structure:
$$\mathcal{U}:=\uparrow\{B_N: N\in\mathcal{N}_0\}$$

Going first step up:

**Uniform Vector Spaces**

Neighborhoods:
$$\mathcal{N}_z:=\{U[z]:U\in\mathcal{U}\}$$

Uniform maps:
$$\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega':\Phi^{-1}(\mathcal{U}')\subseteq\mathcal{U}\}$$

It holds equality:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Homomorphisms:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad\Phi(\mathcal{U})=\mathcal{U}'$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

Suppose one finds:
$$\text{Locally Convex Base}$$

Induced seminorms:
$$\mu_U(x):=\inf\{r\geq0:x\in rU\}$$

Going next step up:

**Locally Convex Spaces**

Basic entourages:
$$B_{\mu\varepsilon}:=\{(x,y):\mu(y-x)<\varepsilon\}\subseteq\Omega\times\Omega$$

Uniform structure:
$$\mathcal{U}:=\uparrow\{B_{\mu\varepsilon}:\mu\in\mathcal{S},\varepsilon>0\}$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad\Phi(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{S}'$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

Suppose one finds:
$$\text{Countable Base}$$

Induced Metric:
$$d(x,y):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{\sigma_k(y-x)}{1+\sigma(y-x)}$$

Going next step up:

**Metrizable Vector Space**

Induced seminorm:
$$\mu(x):=d(x,0)=d(0,x)\geq0$$

Lipschitz maps:
$$\mathcal{C}_L(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega':d(\Phi\cdot,\Phi\cdot)'\leq L_\Phi d(\cdot,\cdot)\}$$

It holds equality:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_L(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_U(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isometric maps:
$$\mathcal{I}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega':d(\Phi\cdot\Phi\cdot)'=d(\cdot,\cdot)\}$$

Homomorphisms:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{I}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad d(\Phi\cdot,\Phi\cdot)'=d(\cdot,\cdot)$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

By construction:
$$d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)\quad(a\in\Omega)$$

Suppose one has:
$$d(\lambda x,\lambda y)=|\lambda|d(x,y)\quad(\lambda\in\mathbb{C})$$

Induced norm:
$$\|x\|:=d(x,0)\geq0$$

Going next step up:

**Normed Spaces**

Induced metric:
$$d(x,y):=\|y-x\|\geq0$$

Lipschitz maps:
$$\mathcal{B}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega':\|\Phi\cdot\|'\leq\|\Phi\|\cdot\|\cdot\|\}$$

It holds equality:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{B}(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{C}_L(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad\|\Phi(\cdot)\|'=\|\cdot\|$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

Suppose one has:
$$\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2$$

Induced scalar product:
$$\langle x,y\rangle:=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha\|x+i^\alpha y\|$$

Going final step up:

**Hilbert Spaces**

Induced norm:
$$\|x\|^2:=\langle x,x\rangle\geq0$$

Orthogonal maps:
$$\mathcal{O}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\{\Phi:\Omega\to\Omega':\langle\Phi\cdot,\Phi\cdot\rangle'=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\}$$

It holds equality:
$$\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{O}(\Omega,\Omega')=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{I}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Homomorphisms:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega,\Omega'):=\mathcal{L}(\Omega,\Omega')\cap\mathcal{O}(\Omega,\Omega')$$

Isomorphic spaces:
$$\Omega\cong\Omega':\iff\Phi:\Omega\leftrightarrow\Omega':\quad \langle\Phi\cdot,\Phi\cdot\rangle'=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$$
$$\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+'\Phi(y)\quad((x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot'\Phi(x)\quad((x,\lambda)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{C})$$

Concluding categories.

Comment: This looks very interesting, but could you define N and U or provide a reference that uses the same notation?

Comment: @user3281410: Sure. Due to Felix Hausdorff [Neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces#Definition_via_neighbourhoods) and [Entourages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: @user3281410: Especially interesting for you: [Hierarchy](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/662029/79762), [Construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/845306/79762), [Completeness](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/835999/79762)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a sequence which converges in $G $. The lower bound implies it converges in $F $ to the same limit.

Suppose you have a sequence which does not converge in $G $. The upper bound implies it does not converge in $F $.

That's all you need, since metric spaces are sequential spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with "the norms induce the same topology".  Then use the fact that a linear transformation is continuous if and only if it is bounded.  And this is one of your inequalities.  For the other direction, use the inverse of that linear transformation.

Comment: This is very intriguing, but I can't figure out what the linear transformation you're referring to should be.  If you view the other norm as a function on the space, isn't it sub-linear and not necessarily linear?

Comment: The linear transformation is the "identity".  From the space with one norm to the space with the other.

Comment: Ok I understand now.  So norms being equivalent is exactly the same as saying that the identity is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @GEdgar: Probably you know already: In general, boundedness does not imply continuity over a TVS.

Comment: @GEdgar: Also continuity of the identity is not sufficient: Consider the real line with $d(x,y):=|y-x|$ and $d'(x,y):=\arctan(y-x)$.

Comment: I hope user knows that Freeze's comments are about non-norm situations.