# figuring out two norms are equivalent

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have difficulty figuring out two norms are equivalent.

Let s be a nonnegatiev real number and K is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $H_{K}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of distributions of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which are supported in K. Then for every $u\in H_{K}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $||u||_{H^s}$ and $||u||_{\dot{H^S}}$ are equivalent.

In the book it says we only need to show $||u||_{L^2}\leq C||u||_{\dot{H^s}}$. I know how to show this, but I don't why by showing this equality we can get the answer. I only know u is compactly supported, what about $\hat{u}$? I guess probably it is not compactly supported. Then I don't know what to do. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: How is $\dot H^s_K$ and its norm defined? And what is this $\hat u$ you're talking about? (And what book are you referring to?)

Answer (score 0):

Two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent iff there is a constans $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that for all $u$
$$\alpha \|u\|_1\leq \|u\|_2\leq\beta \|u\|_1$$
I guess the book asking only one side because the other is already discussed or trivial or so.

Comment: Yes. One side is trivial. And the book shows the other side by showing L2 norm is smaller than $\dot{H^s}$ norm. I know why L2 is smaller than $ \dot{H^s}$ norm, but I don't know why it gives us the answer.

Comment: Are you asking why this is the definition of the equivalency? Look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380191/definition-of-equivalent-norms

Comment: No. The L2 is not the same as the inhomogenous sobolev norm, but the book says we only need to show the L2 norm. This is where I got confused.

Comment: If $\alpha \|u\|_{H_s}\leq \|u\|_{L_2}$ is ok with you and the book shows $\|u\|_{L_2}\leq\beta \|u\|_{H_s}$ then you should be convinced that they are equivalent. But I guess I didn't get your problem yet.

Comment: Why $||u||_{H^s}$ is comparable to $||u||_{L^2}$? I guess that's my question.

Comment: btw, "equivalency" doesn't mean "the same", i.e. it mean the same in a very specifically defined sense.

Comment: most of the norms are comparable\equivalent, so this shouldn't be big surprise.

Comment: But I don't know how to show it... I guess it only holds when u is supported in a compact set.

Comment: it may not be equivalent without this little detail (idk thought if they are or not)

Comment: btw, all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent (but this is not true for infinite dimensional spaces of course)
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional

Comment: Yes. But this case is an infinite space. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Two norms in an infinite space can be equivalent, just not every two. Why do you want to prove their equivalency in the case of not compactly supported function?